# Android SQLiteException "No such table"

Tags: c#, android, sqlite

I get an error when I try to use the getFavorieten(favoriet) method from my DBAdapter. It says there's no such table "Favorieten" while I clearly declared it and it gives me no errors there.

I have two tables and use similar code for both of them. On my first table "Gebruikers" there's no problems at all, but on my table "Favorieten" it doesn't seem to find my table. Here's the code from my DBAdapter. I left out the irrelevant stuff.

public class DBAdapter {

```
//Gebruikers

static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
static final String KEY_WACHTWOORD = "wachtwoord";
static final String KEY_KADNR = "kadnr";
static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";


static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AndroidDB";
static final String DATABASE_TABLE_GEBRUIKERS = "Gebruikers";
static final String DATABASE_TABLE_FAVORIETEN = "Favorieten";

static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;

static final String CREATE_TABLE_GEBRUIKERS = "create table Gebruikers (email text primary key, wachtwoord text not null);";
static final String CREATE_TABLE_FAVORIETEN = "create table Favorieten (id integer primary key auto_increment, kadnr text not null, foreign key(gebruiker) references Gebruikers(email) on delete cascade);";

final Context context;

DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}




private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_GEBRUIKERS);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FAVORIETEN);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Gebruikers");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Favorieten");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}


public DBAdapter open()
{

    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
    }
    return this;


}


public void close()
{
    DBHelper.close();
} 


public Gebruiker getGebruiker(Gebruiker gebruiker) throws SQLException
{
    String email = gebruiker.getEmail();
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_GEBRUIKERS, new String[] {KEY_EMAIL, KEY_WACHTWOORD}, KEY_EMAIL
            + "='" + email + "'", null, null, null, null, null);

        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        if(mCursor.getCount()==1) {
            return createGebruiker(mCursor);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
}

public Favoriet getFavoriet(Favoriet favoriet) throws SQLException
{
    String kadnr = favoriet.getKadnr();
    String email = favoriet.getEmail();
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_FAVORIETEN, new String[]{KEY_KADNR, KEY_EMAIL}, KEY_KADNR + "= ? AND " + KEY_EMAIL + "= ?", new String[]{kadnr, email}, null, null, null, null, null);

    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    if(mCursor.getCount()==1) {
        return createFavoriet(mCursor);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}



private Gebruiker createGebruiker(Cursor mCursor) {
    Gebruiker gebruiker = new Gebruiker();
    gebruiker.setEmail(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL)));
    gebruiker.setWachtwoord(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_WACHTWOORD)));
    return gebruiker;
}

private Favoriet createFavoriet(Cursor mCursor) {
    Favoriet favoriet = new Favoriet();
    favoriet.setKadnr(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_KADNR)));
    favoriet.setEmail(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL)));
    return favoriet;
}




}
```

Comment: Most obvious explanation is that you are getting an exception when you try to create the table -- nothing like that is coming up in the log?

Comment: No, it doesn't give an exception when I create them, only when I try to use the getFavorieten() method.

Comment: First Remove(Uninstall) Your old application from your device and again install it.

Comment: I changed the database version and reïnstalled the application, still the same error.

Comment: same problem i was facing today did everything finally got working when change the database name to different one also instead of "create table" i used "create table if not exists" not sure what was the problem

Comment: Tried this, didn't help either.